# how to remove existing image in jQuery.filer

Tags: php, jquery, plugins

I'm using a great plugin: https://github.com/CreativeDream/jquery.filer

Only uploaded file can be Deleted, but added image file can Not be removed from server

```
  files: [{
          name: "photo_2016-09-23_21-25-48dfdgr.jpg",
          size: 5453,
          type: "image/jpg",
          file: ".php/uploads/photo_2016-09-23_21-25-48.jpg",
       },{
          name: "photo_2016-09-23_21-25-48dfdf.jpg",
          size: 9503,
          type: "image/png",
          file: "./php/uploads/photo_2016-09-23_21-25-48.jpg",
 }],
```

remove file and delete in php does not work.

all codes

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Example 2
    $("#filer_input2").filer({
        limit: null,
        maxSize: null,
        extensions: null,
        changeInput: '<div class="jFiler-input-dragDrop"><div class="jFiler-input-inner"><div class="jFiler-input-icon"><i class="icon-jfi-cloud-up-o"></i></div><div class="jFiler-input-text"><h3>Drag&Drop files here</h3> <span style="display:inline-block; margin: 15px 0">or</span></div><a class="jFiler-input-choose-btn blue">Browse Files</a></div></div>',
        showThumbs: true,
        theme: "dragdropbox",

        templates: {
            box: '<ul class="jFiler-items-list jFiler-items-grid"></ul>',
            item: '<li class="jFiler-item">\
                        <div class="jFiler-item-container">\
                            <div class="jFiler-item-inner">\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-thumb">\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-status"></div>\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-thumb-overlay">\
                                        <div class="jFiler-item-info">\
                                            <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">\
                                                <span class="jFiler-item-title"><b title="{{fi-name}}">{{fi-name}}</b></span>\
                                                <span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-size2}}</span>\
                                            </div>\
                                        </div>\
                                    </div>\
                                    {{fi-image}}\
                                </div>\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-assets jFiler-row">\
                                    <ul class="list-inline pull-left">\
                                        <li>{{fi-progressBar}}</li>\
                                    </ul>\
                                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right">\
                                        <li><a class="icon-jfi-trash jFiler-item-trash-action"></a></li>\
                                    </ul>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </li>',
            itemAppend: '<li class="jFiler-item">\
                            <div class="jFiler-item-container">\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-inner">\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-thumb">\
                                        <div class="jFiler-item-status"></div>\
                                        <div class="jFiler-item-thumb-overlay">\
                                            <div class="jFiler-item-info">\
                                                <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">\
                                                    <span class="jFiler-item-title"><b title="{{fi-name}}">{{fi-name}}</b></span>\
                                                    <span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-size2}}</span>\
                                                </div>\
                                            </div>\
                                        </div>\
                                        {{fi-image}}\
                                    </div>\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-assets jFiler-row">\
                                        <ul class="list-inline pull-left">\
                                            <li><span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-icon}}</span></li>\
                                        </ul>\
                                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right">\
                                            <li><a class="icon-jfi-trash jFiler-item-trash-action"></a></li>\
                                        </ul>\
                                    </div>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                        </li>',
            progressBar: '<div class="bar"></div>',
            itemAppendToEnd: false,
            canvasImage: true,
            removeConfirmation: true,
            _selectors: {
                list: '.jFiler-items-list',
                item: '.jFiler-item',
                progressBar: '.bar',
                remove: '.jFiler-item-trash-action'
            }
        },
        dragDrop: {
            dragEnter: null,
            dragLeave: null,
            drop: null,
            dragContainer: null,
        },
        uploadFile: {
            url: "./php/ajax_upload_file.php",
            data: null,
            type: 'POST',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            synchron: true,
            beforeSend: function(){},
            success: function(data, itemEl, listEl, boxEl, newInputEl, inputEl, id){
                var parent = itemEl.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").parent(),
                    new_file_name = JSON.parse(data),
                    filerKit = inputEl.prop("jFiler");

                filerKit.files_list[id].name = new_file_name;

                itemEl.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").fadeOut("slow", function(){
                    $("<div class=\"jFiler-item-others text-success\"><i class=\"icon-jfi-check-circle\"></i> Success</div>").hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn("slow");
                });
            },
            error: function(el){
                var parent = el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").parent();
                el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").fadeOut("slow", function(){
                    $("<div class=\"jFiler-item-others text-error\"><i class=\"icon-jfi-minus-circle\"></i> Error</div>").hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn("slow");
                });
            },
            statusCode: null,
            onProgress: null,
            onComplete: null
        },

        addMore: true,
          files: [{
                  name: "photo_2016-09-23_21-25-48dfdgr.jpg",
                  size: 5453,
                  type: "image/jpg",
                  file: ".php/uploads/photo_2016-09-23_21-25-48.jpg",
               },{
                  name: "photo_2016-09-23_21-25-48dfdf.jpg",
                  size: 9503,
                  type: "image/png",
                  file: "./php/uploads/photo_2016-09-23_21-25-48.jpg",
         }],

        allowDuplicates: false,
        clipBoardPaste: true,
        excludeName: null,
        beforeRender: null,
        afterRender: null,
        beforeShow: null,
        beforeSelect: null,
        onSelect: null,
        afterShow: null,
        onRemove: function(itemEl, file, id, listEl, boxEl, newInputEl, inputEl){
            var filerKit = inputEl.prop("jFiler"),
                file_name = filerKit.files_list[id].name;
                console.log(file_name);
            $.post('./php/ajax_remove_file.php', {file: file_name});
        },
        onEmpty: null,
        options: null,
        dialogs: {
            alert: function(text) {
                return alert(text);
            },
            confirm: function (text, callback) {
                confirm(text) ? callback() : null;
            }
        },
        captions: {
            button: "Choose Files",
            feedback: "Choose files To Upload",
            feedback2: "files were chosen",
            drop: "Drop file here to Upload",
            removeConfirmation: "Are you sure you want to remove this file?",
            errors: {
                filesLimit: "Only {{fi-limit}} files are allowed to be uploaded.",
                filesType: "Only Images are allowed to be uploaded.",
                filesSize: "{{fi-name}} is too large! Please upload file up to {{fi-maxSize}} MB.",
                filesSizeAll: "Files you've choosed are too large! Please upload files up to {{fi-maxSize}} MB."
            }
        }
    });
})
```

please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change

```
file_name = filerKit.files_list[id].name;
```

to

```
file_name = filerKit.files_list[id].file.name;
```

in the onRemove the name variable isn't set when a file array of existing files is passed in however it exists in the file object that is created and passed to the onRemove function.  Use it if it exists if not grab the other one.  If you are modifying the saved file name on the server it's not updated on new uploads so it's important to use the name returned in uploadFile

```
onRemove: function(itemEl, file, id, listEl, boxEl, newInputEl, inputEl){
        var file_name;
        var filerKit = inputEl.prop("jFiler");

        if (typeof filerKit.files_list[id].name === 'undefined') {
            file_name = filerKit.files_list[id].file.name;
        }
        else {
            file_name = filerKit.files_list[id].name;
        }

        $.post('./php/ajax_remove_file.php', {file: file_name});
    },
```